# How to get value from kendo numerictextbox?

Tags: javascript, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following HTML/RAZOR code in my HTML file to populate group names and a numeric textbox for each group in table format:

```
 <div id="minStaffingSettings" style="width: 400px;">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Minimum Staffing</legend>
                <div>
                    <table>
                        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.AvailableUserGroups.ToList().Count; i++)
                        {
                            <tr id="updateStaffing_@i">
                                <td>
                                    <label>@Model.AvailableUserGroups.ToList()[i].Name</label>
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AvailableUserGroups.ToList()[i].Name)
                                </td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>
                                    @(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(model => model.AvailableUserGroups.ToList()[i].StaffingMinimum)
                                .Min(0)
                                .Step(1)
                                .Format("#0.00")
                                .Decimals(0)
                                .Events(e => e.Change("UpdateStaffingMinimums")))

                                </td>
                                <td><label> (0 = No minimum) </label></td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </table>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
```

from UpdateStaffingMinimums method I'm trying to pull the values from each numerictextbox that was created:

```
function UpdateStaffingMinimums()
{

    var assignmentTypeID = @Model.AssignmentTypeID;
    var groupCount = @Model.AvailableUserGroups.Count();
    var sumHour = 0;
    if ($("#HasMinimumStaffing").is(':checked'))
    {

        for (var i = 0; i < groupCount; i++)
        {
            var it = $("#updateStaffing_"+i);//.data("kendoNumericTextBox").value();
            console.log(it);

        }


    }
}
```

I get an output in the console log as expected; but when I changeto :

```
var it = $("#updateStaffing_"+i).data("kendoNumericTextBox").value();
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

How do I pull the value from the numeric textbox?

Comment: You need to call `.data("kendoNumericTextBox")` on the textbox element itself, not the row it's in.

Comment: How do I get reference to the element from the row? I'm complete newbie with JQuery -_-

Comment: I've forgotten most of the specifics of Kendo (you should be able to find them in their documentation), but something like `$("#updateStaffing_"+i).find('.k-numerictextbox')` seems like it should work.

Comment: Thanks this pointed me in the right direction to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across a similar issue of getting the value of a Kendo numerictextbox. I solved my problem by just using jQuery method .val(). In your case, it will be:

```
var it = $("#updateStaffing_"+i).val();
```

I hope it helps.